# Why have 3 songs from a recent download from iTunes got a ''! next to them and won't sync to playlist?

Tags: data-synchronization, ipod, data-transfer

We paid for and downloaded an album from iTunes store and 3 of the tracks have an exclamation mark next to them and we cannot move them to the playlist to sync with the ipod. Does anyone know what we can do about that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You are seeing the exclamation point because iTunes doesn't know where to find the song.

Using iCloud, you can download those three songs again without having to pay. You can do this by going to the iTunes store, navigate to Quick Links on the right, and click the Purchased link. Search for your songs and you can redownload them.